# Adding up variables in python

Tags: python-3.x, global-variables

I'm trying to get python to add up the values of a points system in a game I'm making and at the end of the game it tells you what you got, kinda like those house quizzes for Harry Potter and stuff. But no matter what I try Python will not print the final answers I hope that made sense, probably not.

But this is what I have so far:

```
P1_points = 0
P2_points = 0
P3_points = 0
P4_points = 0
conditionP1 = ['P1_points > P2_points and P3_points and P4_points']    

def Quiz():
    #Question
    name = input("when you are ready type the letter in front of your answer here. > ")

if name =="A" or name == "a":
    global P1_points
    P1_points += 3
    global P2_points
    P2_points += 1



if name == "B" or name == "b":
        global P3_points
        P3_points += 1
        global P4_points
        P4_points += 1

if name == "C" or name == "c":

    P2_points += 1
    P4_ponts += 1

if name == "D" or name == "d":

    P1_points += 1
    P3_ponts += 1

if name == "E" or name == "e":

    P1_points += 1
    P2_points += 1
    P3_points += 1
    P4_points += 1


if conditionP1== True:
    print("YAY!!!!")
```

I might just be over complicating things... I'll take all the help I can get

Comment: Can you better explain what you are trying to achieve and what is actually wrong, because your code is not very clear? Why are you using `global` when all variables are in the same scope? Why you never call the `Quiz` function? `name` is not defined. And what did you mean for `conditionP1` to be?

Answer (score 0):

Make it a class. You can then read  points from the class:

```
class MyClass:
    P2_points = 0
    P4_points = 0
    def quiz(self):
        name = input("when you are ready type the letter in front of your answer here. > ")
        return name

    def eval(self,name):
        if name == "C" or name == "c":
            self.P2_points += 1
            self.P4_points += 1
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
app = MyClass()
n = app.quiz()
app.eval(n)
print(app.P2_points)
```

Good luck!